# RegularExpressionValidator only checks once

Tags: asp.net, validation, reg-expressionvalidator

I have a form in which I would like guests to enter their `name`, `address` etc...
On each field I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` and a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mailNameTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="70" ValidationGroup="mail"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="mailNameTextBox_RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name can only have letters or spaces." ControlToValidate="mailNameTextBox" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z' ']" ValidationGroup="mail" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="mailNameTextBox_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name field is required." ControlToValidate="mailNameTextBox" ValidationGroup="mail" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When I enter a name that includes a number (ie. fails the Regex) and `"tab"` out of the `TextBox`, the `RegexValidator` is instantly displayed with a *, and the form fails to submit. But when I go back and remove the number (ie. pass the `Regex`), the `Validator` doesn't seem to re-check the input, and the form will forever fail to submit.

Is there a way to always fire the Validation when leaving the box rather than just the first time (besides calling a Validation method upon the TextBox losing focus). I would have thought this would be automatic?

I have spent some time trying to find an answer to this, and I'm not sure how to word my question to "thouroughly research it", so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

I did see this one:
[ASP.NET: RegularExpressionValidator Doesn't reCheck the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931317/asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator-doesnt-recheck-the-input)
but it didn't really help in my case.

Comment: Your validation expression should be: "[\w\s]*"

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I was looking for completely the wrong thing. I think it's about time I do some research into regex's - I've been avoiding them until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation expression is this:

```
[a-zA-Z' ']
```

Which means: exactly one letter or one apostroph or one space.

You probably want to use something like the following:

```
[\w\s]*
```

Which means: any number of letters or whitespaces.